# Adding two rows in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

[image: Picture]

I have a table called A and I want to create a new table that has the same values but at the end of the table, another row called "total", that does the following computation:

(A+BB+ES)-(BD+L+S).

Essentially, I want the same table as I have in the attached screenshot, but with an added row called Total that has the value of "32" which came from (A+BB+ES)-(BD+L+S).

so far my code is the following:

```
proc sql;
create table A as select 'Total' as Name from A
union
select * from A;
quit
```

[image: What I want]

Comment: Please do not include [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be text in your question.

Comment: @Stu you need 10 rep to include images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following meet expectations?

```
select name, count
from A
union all
select 'Total', 
  Sum(case when name in ('a','bb','es') then count end)
  -Sum(case when name in ('bd','l','s') then count end)
from A
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much sir. I want to upvote your answer but I do not have enough reputation to do so